# How can I compile astropy (which uses numpy) for a kivy android installation?

Tags: android, python, numpy, kivy, astropy

I'm trying to use kivy to create an android app that makes use of astropy. The difficulty is that astropy makes use of numpy during its installation, and I haven't been able to get it to successfully load the numpy libraries. I believe the problem is that it's finding the libraries compiled for ARM architecture - how can I get it to find the correct libraries for use at the point of building?

I'm using the linux virtual machine provided by kivy. The numpy recipe itself works fine. For astropy I've created a `recipe.sh` script containing, alongside the standard settings, this build function:

```
function build_astropy() {
    cd $BUILD_astropy
    export BUILDLIB_PATH="$BUILD_hostpython/build/lib.linux-`uname -m`-2.7/"
    export PYTHONPATH=$SITEPACKAGES_PATH:$BUILDLIB_PATH
    push_arm
    try $HOSTPYTHON setup.py install
    pop_arm
}
```

The `BUILDLIB_PATH` lines allow it to successfully find and import the `_io.so` module - I copied this from another recipe that was dealing with similar architecture issues. But when I try to run the distribute script:

```
./distribute.sh -f -m "astropy kivy" -d astropy
```

it tries to import numpy and I get this error:

```
ImportError: /home/kivy/android/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file does exist but is presumably compiled for ARM. I tried adding the local numpy installation:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/
```

to the `BUILDLIB_PATH` but it made no difference. Does anyone have any tips on getting kivy to find the right libraries when building?

Comment: Haven't there been earlier questions about compiling `numpy` for `android`?  The normal `linux` installation uses many extra `C` libraries (and even a Fortran compiler).

Comment: I don't know anything about kivy but it sounds like you might have something goofy on your `$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @hpaulj The step of compiling numpy for android works fine. My issue is that astropy needs to import the linux-compiled numpy in order to build, and I don't know how to get it to find the correct libraries at that point.

Comment: So can you run `numpy` on your Android device?  The `numpy` `.so` files have to be linked to Android code, not linux code.

Comment: Yes, when I do a separate numpy distribution: `./distribute.sh -f -m "numpy kivy" -d numpy` it works fine and numpy runs on the android device.

Answer (score 1):

The backtrace for the failing import contains `get_numpy_include_path()` in it, which is from `astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py`. Looking at the source code for numpy's `get_include()`, it won't work on a system when cross compiling, so even if you managed to build numpy for the host Python then it would get the incorrect value.

Patching astropy to allow the numpy include path (where to find files such as `numpyconfig.h`) to be provided via the environment will fix this, so create `recipes/patches/add_numpy_include.patch` containing the following:

```
--- astropy-0.4.4.orig/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py 2015-02-15 18:16:02.135642283 -0600
+++ astropy-0.4.4/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py  2015-02-15 18:15:10.985674250 -0600
@@ -1307,6 +1307,11 @@
     # install, since Numpy may still think it's in "setup mode", when
     # in fact we're ready to use it to build astropy now.

+    # Allow the environment to override the include path, to allow
+    # cross-compilation
+    if 'NUMPY_INCLUDE_PATH' in os.environ:
+        return os.environ['NUMPY_INCLUDE_PATH']
+
     if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
         import builtins
         if hasattr(builtins, '__NUMPY_SETUP__'):
```

If you try to build with just this patch then it leads to a build error about `struct lconv` so create a second patch file, `recipes/patches/lconv_fix.patch` containing the following:

```
--- astropy-0.4.4.orig/cextern/wcslib/C/wcsutil.c   2015-02-15 18:07:46.549935299 -0600
+++ astropy-0.4.4/cextern/wcslib/C/wcsutil.c    2015-02-15 18:36:07.062452345 -0600
@@ -247,7 +247,7 @@

 {
   struct lconv *locale_data = localeconv();
-  const char *decimal_point = locale_data->decimal_point;
+  const char *decimal_point = ".";

   if (decimal_point[0] != '.' || decimal_point[1] != 0) {
     size_t decimal_point_len = strlen(decimal_point);
@@ -311,7 +311,7 @@

 {
   struct lconv *locale_data = localeconv();
-  const char *decimal_point = locale_data->decimal_point;
+  const char *decimal_point = ".";

   if (decimal_point[0] != '.' || decimal_point[1] != 0) {
     char *out = outbuf;
--- astropy-0.4.4.orig/cextern/cfitsio/fitscore.c   2015-02-15 18:07:46.553935299 -0600
+++ astropy-0.4.4/cextern/cfitsio/fitscore.c    2015-02-15 18:41:16.626440539 -0600
@@ -9226,7 +9226,7 @@

     if (!decimalpt) { /* only do this once for efficiency */
        lcc = localeconv();   /* set structure containing local decimal point symbol */
-       decimalpt = *(lcc->decimal_point);
+       decimalpt = '.';
     }

     errno = 0;
@@ -9296,7 +9296,7 @@

     if (!decimalpt) { /* only do this once for efficiency */
        lcc = localeconv();   /* set structure containing local decimal point symbol */
-       decimalpt = *(lcc->decimal_point);
+       decimalpt = '.';
     }

     errno = 0;
```

The lconv fix isn't really a great fix as it assumes that the locale on the Android device has '.' as the decimal separator, but the [patch for numpy](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/numpy/patches/fix-numpy.patch) in the official repository does this, so astropy will fail in the same situations as numpy.

Using numpy 1.7.1 and a recipe as per the [official repository](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/recipes/numpy), the following `prebuild_astropy()` and `build_astropy()` function works for astropy 0.4.4, invoking `./distribute.sh -m "numpy astropy kivy" -d astropy`:

```
function prebuild_astropy() {
    cd $BUILD_astropy

    if [ -f .patched ]; then
        return
    fi

    try patch -p1 < $RECIPE_astropy/patches/add_numpy_include.patch
    try patch -p1 < $RECIPE_astropy/patches/lconv_fix.patch
    touch .patched
    true
}

function build_astropy() {
    cd $BUILD_astropy
    export BUILDLIB_PATH="$BUILD_hostpython/build/lib.linux-`uname -m`-2.7/"
    export PYTHONPATH=$SITEPACKAGES_PATH:$BUILDLIB_PATH
    export NUMPY_INCLUDE_PATH="$BUILD_PATH/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include"
    push_arm
    try $BUILD_PATH/python-install/bin/python.host setup.py install
    pop_arm
    unset BUILDLIB_PATH
    unset PYTHONPATH
    unset NUMPY_INCLUDE_PATH
}
```

Comment: That's strange that `lcc->decimal_point;` doesn't work on that platform.  Why is that?  I wonder if some form of these patches are worth including in Astropy (the latter not so much unless it used an ifdef of some sort).